# How can i add file and object on server in angular?

Tags: c#, .net, angular, server

I am trying adding document on my server in angular but i don't know idea for how can i doing that.

That is my controller. How can i adding document in angular? Thank you for help me from now.

[image]

I can add with Post Man:
[image]

I tried form action but it didn't work:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a form (directly in the page DOM, or strictly in JS code) where the type for one of the form `<input/>` fields is `File`. Populate the form fields, and submit it to the URL of your controller action.

```
<form action="/api/lessons/add">
  <input type="file" id="file" name="file">
  <input type="submit">Upload</input>
</form>
```

P.S. You *may* run into a parameter binding issue if you declare both the `file` and `lesson` parameters as `[FromForm]`.

**EDIT:**
Here's a JavaScript sample:

```
function uploadFile(afile) {
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.method = "POST";
    form.action = "/documents/add";

    var element1 = document.createElement("input"); 
    element1.type=file;
    element1.id="file";
    element1.name="file";
    element1.value=afile;
    form.appendChild(element1);  

    document.body.appendChild(form);

    form.submit();
}
```

Comment: I tried but it didn't work :( Thank you but 'how can i doing in angular' i need to learn this.

Comment: Angular is just JavaScript. I updated my answer with an example. Take a look.

Comment: I don't know javascript and i am new in Angular :,) Where i can call this function? How can i give parameter? Actually there is formgroup in Angular and how can i learn use that method? Thank you again :,) My backend do work, i did test with PostMan.

Comment: Fine. Forget the JavaScript (for now), and create a form on your page like the one I showed in my answer instead (you can read the Angular docs to learn how to do that here: [Building a template-driven form](https://angular.io/guide/forms)).

Comment: I will try :,) Thank you again.